# AG-Grid 'columnMoved' event never fires

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want to save my grid state to local storage whenever the user re-order columns.

I thought maybe I'm just using the wrong event name, but tried various variations including dragStopped without any luck

The `onColumnMoved` method in my code never get executed in the following:

````
            <ag-grid-angular 
                #someGrid  class="ag-theme-balham" 
                [rowData]="model" 
                [columnDefs]="colDefs"
                [enableFilter]="true" 
                [enableSorting]="true" 
                [animateRows]="true" 
                [enableRangeSelection]="true" 
                [enableColResize]="true"
                rowSelection="multiple" 
                (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
                (columnMoved )="onColumnMoved($event)">
            </ag-grid-angular>```


I'm using the free version for what it matter, Angular 6
````

Comment: Hi, can you provide stackblitz repro? I tried it on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-yeyay7) and here it's working, if you check console

Comment: remove space after columnMoved event. see below answer in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the event is not firing because there is space after `(columnMoved )` event If you remove that space then the code will work.

```
<ag-grid-angular 
                #someGrid  class="ag-theme-balham" 
                [rowData]="model" 
                [columnDefs]="colDefs"
                [enableFilter]="true" 
                [enableSorting]="true" 
                [animateRows]="true" 
                [enableRangeSelection]="true" 
                [enableColResize]="true"
                rowSelection="multiple" 
                (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
                (columnMoved )="onColumnMoved($event)">
            </ag-grid-angular>
```

[**Here is solution on plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cd1t4nk8wS3N8HoKnQNl?p=preview)

Comment: oh dear..in my defense I'm working while having the flu this week.  :-(